# Is there a max. limit for lines of code in Aptana 3?

Tags: aptana, limit, lines-of-code

i work with Aptana 3.0.6. 
Today i opend a CSS file with 10302 lines of code and i can only make two or three click's and than Aptana freezes vor 5 seconds (or more).
Is there a limit for lines of code?
How can I fix the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: It's likely a memory issue. You might want to try another editor (such as TextPad) that handles large files well.

Comment: added aptana tag to the question as it seems most relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling code highlighting for files that large. With files longer than 1000 rows I sometimes notice un-styled, ie. white, code flickering when I quickly jump up or down in the view.